# Model Class Override not working for Enterprise Edition

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am stuck on overriding model class only in EE version.

**My config.xml**

```
<models>
        <pos>
            ...................
        </pos>
        <pos_mysql4>
            ....................
        </pos_mysql4>

        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order>DigitalCinema_Pos_Model_Sales_Taken</order>
                <order_invoice>DigitalCinema_Pos_Model_Sales_Order_Invoice</order_invoice>
                <order_pdf_invoice>DigitalCinema_Pos_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                <order_pdf_items_invoice_default>DigitalCinema_Pos_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default</order_pdf_items_invoice_default>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>

        <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_pdf_items_invoice>DigitalCinema_Pos_Model_Bundle_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice</sales_order_pdf_items_invoice>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>

    </models>
```

**and my DigitalCinema/Pos/Model/Sales/Taken.php**

```
class DigitalCinema_Pos_Model_Sales_Taken extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
     public function sendNewOrderEmail()
     {
         ........
     }

   ..............
}
```

**Problem**

See following line:
`<order>DigitalCinema_Pos_Model_Sales_Taken</order>`

Only this one `(sales_model_order.php)` is not getting overridden.
All others are working.

***I can also confirm that it is working in community version.***

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

As Marius suggested, I have checked module conflict and can see there is another module rewriting same class. However, that module is not overwriting the class I am trying overwrite. 
Now, I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815717/multiple-modules-overriding-same-core-file-in-magento). And would like to use **Option 2**. But it is not working.
Now my **Taken.php** becomes as follows:

```
class DigitalCinema_Pos_Model_Sales_Taken extends Other_Module_Model_Order
```

Anything I am missing on this?

Comment: Check if you have an other module rewriteing the order model. Here is a small script that let's you do this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1600/146

Comment: @Marius That's good to know, but I have tested by editing core file `order.php` and it does executes. That means that particular function is not overwritten.

Comment: Just to make sure...did you clear the cache and disabled the compilation?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared cache and compilation is disabled at the moment. Thanks

Comment: Is your module loaded? Generate an parsing error in the config.xml by renaming the closing `</config>` to `</blabla>`. Site should blow up after cleaning config cache, with developer mode turned on. If not, check your modules file. Inject some logging into Mage_Core_Module_Config, loadModuleCache and related, if you don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Melvyn Yes my module is loaded and can confirm that all other rewrite is taking effect.

Comment: @Marius Yes, there is another extension overwriting this class, but it hasn't overwriting the function. Now, how do I get over it?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments...the order model is overwritten by an other class.
You need to make your class extend the other class like you did

```
class DigitalCinema_Pos_Model_Sales_Taken extends Other_Module_Model_Order
```

and you make your module depend on the other module so yours is loaded after it.
For this, make your `app/etc/modules/DigitalCinema_Pos.xml` file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DigitalCinema_Pos>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Other_Module />
                <Mage_Sales />
             </depends>
        </DigitalCinema_Pos>
    </modules>
</config>
```

clear the cache and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering what will happen if `Other_Module` is disabled? Will site throw error? Is there a way to make it work automatically even if `other_module` is disabled or removed?