# How to add button in customer order history frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

[image]

i want to add custom button in customer order history grid. how can i can do that through custom module..

Comment: Yo can check this link - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69877/magento-add-button-on-order-view-page-with-custom-module

Comment: that que for admin grid i want button in frontend

Comment: i want to add button in my orders grid using custom module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your can `rewrite` the this `phtml file`

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/history.phtml
```

check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247772/magento-how-override-sales-order-history-block-class-mage-sales-block-order-h) to override the block

Comment: How can i rewrite this phtml file?