# Magento overwrite payment information block

Tags: checkout, overrides, module, payment

I'm writing custom checkout section and I'm trying to overwrite payment information section of Magento and use existing methods defined in `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container`.

What I'm doing?
config.xml contains

```
  <blocks>
        <zigycheckout>
            <class>Medex_ZigyCheckout_Block</class>
        </zigycheckout>
        <payment>
            <rewrite><form_container>Medex_ZigyCheckout_Block_Form_Container</form_container>
            </rewrite>
        </payment>
    </blocks>
```

Block class is defined as `class Medex_ZigyCheckout_Block_Form_Container extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container`

which contains methods which as already defined in `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container`
like

```
  public function getMethodTitle(Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract $method)
    {
        $form = $this->getChild('payment.method.' . $method->getCode());
        if ($form && $form->hasMethodTitle()) {
            return $form->getMethodTitle();
        }
        return $method->getTitle();
    }
```

but when I call following function in my phtml I'm not getting any return from my function. I think my block is not properly overwritten due to which it's not hitting my block method?

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?>
```

Even the calls like `$method = $this->getMethod()` is not working.

Do I need to overwrite Payment information related Models also so that these functions should work properly?

Comment: Have you checked if any other extension is overwriting that block? Check this [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-class-rewrites/1600#1600).

Comment: only one block is overwriting `[payment/form_container] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Medex_ZigyCheckout_Block_Form_Container
                )`

Comment: Did you clean the cache inbetween? Did you check if your block is used? You could enable template hints incl. block names to see if your block is present. How/where do you set the method payment code and title that should be used for return? Maybe you can update your answer with some more details.

Comment: Thanks Anna. Issue was with using block type. I was calling another template in my present template keeping the block type same as for current template due to which my block functions were not loading.