# Customer Class Rewrite Magento Enterprise Edition

Tags: magento-enterprise, overrides, customer-account

I am facing a strange issue. Bascially I need to rewrite the customer authentication logic. So as to rewrite `authenticate()` method I have created a small module. The code for the module is as below:

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nutricentre_Customermigration>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Nutricentre_Customermigration>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
           <customer>
               <rewrite>
                   <customer>Nutricentre_Customermigration_Model_Customer</customer>
               </rewrite>
           </customer>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Customer.php**

```
<?php
class Nutricentre_Customermigration_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer{
     public function authenticate($login, $password){
        echo $login;
        die;
     }
}
```

The rewrite works perfectly fine with Magento Community Edition but its not working on my Enterprise Copy.

Is there any change in rewrite logic for enterprise edition? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: i don't think so. check any other module is rewrite the same model ?

Comment: Yes it was a third party extension that was rewriting. I overlooked it..

Comment: okay....... good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my observation, the rewrite method for both community and enterprise edition is same. I missed one third party module which was rewriting Mage_Customer.

To check the override, I used a script written by @Marius [How do I get a list of all class rewrites?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-class-rewrites/1600#1600)