# Apply patch not working supee-5345

Tags: magento-1.7, security, patches

Check my site with Magento 1.7.x detected that would solve several problems patching the project. I did, clean the cache of my project but it has not worked yet.

```
bash PATCH_SUPEE-5345_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-02-10-08-11-22.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

[magereport](https://www.magereport.com)

My site was abandoned a while and we find that suffered hacking. Solve all problems and now everything works fine. Now I want my application patching to avoid me problems and I have not been able to get. I get a good response but by checking with that application is still not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

That means the patch was applied. However, if the patched classes are locally overridden, it does not help.

Please look if the `app/code/core` files listed in `etc/applied.patches.list` are also present in `app/code/local`, or the classes are rewritten (see: [How do I get a list of all class rewrites?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-class-rewrites)).

If so, you have to apply the changes from the patch manually in these files (or remove the overrides if you can)