# How to get list of overridden controllers?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, overrides, controllers

Is it possible to get list of all overridden controllers ?

[How do I get a list of all class rewrites?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-class-rewrites) mainly applies for blocks, helpers and models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The xpath solution works also for controller overrides, if you modify it to:

```
print_r( Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->xpath('//routers/*/args/modules/../..'));
```

Note that not all of these are actual "overrides", some just add new methods to existing routes. For example, all custom admin controllers will show up below `Mage_Adminhtml` because they all are added to the `adminhtml` route.

Answer (score 4):

I also highly recommend n98's Magento CLI toolkit, n98-magerun.
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

To get an output of rewrites you would do `n98-magerun.phar dev:module:rewrite:list`

You can also check for conflicts specifically by using `n98-magerun.phar dev:module:rewrite:conflicts`

Comment: This doesn't include controller overrides, only models, blocks and helpers.